# Special character in Search in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to retrieve the contact names based on the keyed search string. It performs good for the English alphabets and behaves strangely for special chars such as _,/,\,%

My query in the function is similar to

```
SELECT contact_name FROM contacts WHERE LOWER(contact_name) LIKE LOWER('_McDonald%') ORDER BY LOWER(contact_name) ASC LIMIT 1;
```

It looks like, during searching, it retrieves all the contact names instead of the desired. The similar bizarre happens for the above mentioned special chars. I need to support these. How do I educate postgres to consider these chars? Please guide me.

Thanks and Regards,
Siva.

Comment: For ex, let's assume contacts: McDonalds, _McDonalds, __McDonalds, Mc_Donalds,%McDonalds, __McDonalds, Mc%Donalds. I might search '_M%', '%_%', '%M%','M%' etc. Make sure to differentiate between the wildcard char '%' and the ordinary special char '%'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to complete the picture:

You can also use the ESCAPE clause to specify the character for escaping the wildcards. This is useful if you'd like to include e.g. a `\` in your search string.

```
SELECT contact_name 
FROM contacts 
WHERE LOWER(contact_name) LIKE LOWER('@_McDonald%') ESCAPE '@'
ORDER BY LOWER(contact_name) ASC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Btw: I would recommend to turn on the configuration option [`standard_conforming_strings`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS) to avoid confusion (Haes' answer avoids this problem by using the `E'` syntax). 
Since 9.1 this is the default mode anyway.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what PostgreSQL version you are using, but make sure you escape any special characters (_, %, \, ...) if you want to match them literally as it is described in the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-matching.html).

Assuming you want to search for any contact names that start with `_McDonald`:

```
SELECT contact_name FROM contacts 
WHERE LOWER(contact_name) LIKE LOWER(E'\\_McDonald%')
ORDER BY LOWER(contact_name) ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a prepended E in the where clause before the string using **double** backslashes to escape the following character:

```
WHERE LOWER(contact_name) LIKE LOWER(E'\\_McDonald%')
```

**OR** you may do the appended escape clause as below:

```
WHERE LOWER(contact_name) LIKE LOWER('@_McDonald%') ESCAPE '@'
```

> Note the former method will work with the clauses LIKE, SIMILAR TO and NOT SIMILAR TO, but the above method will work as well with more powerful POSIX regular expressions like ~, ~*,
>   !~, !~*

In the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/functions-matching.html) you can also see some functions that may be of use as well such as `regexp_replace` where you could try this to escape special characters in the contact_name field:

```
SELECT 
regexp_replace(contact_name, '([!$()*+.:<=>?[\\\]^{|}-])', '\\\1', 'g') 
FROM 
contacts 
WHERE
LOWER(contact_name) LIKE LOWER('_McDonald%') 
ORDER BY 
LOWER(contact_name) ASC LIMIT 1;
```